# Unusual character when writing to file

Tags: c

I've created a struct with 2 char[] and one int. I created an array of this struct and `scanf`ed several inputs to store data into the array. Then I used `fprintf` to write this data to the file. But when I open the file I get `û` before every new record. Idk why is it happening.

Here's the relevant code:

```
FILE *outputFile=fopen("1021.txt","ab");
int tickets=0,i=1;
struct air s[30];
printf("\nEnter Number of tickets:");
scanf("%d",&tickets);
for (i=1;i<=tickets;i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter the name\t");
    scanf("%s",&s[i].name);
    printf("\nEnter the phone number\t");
    scanf("%s",&s[i].phoneNo);
    printf("\n Enter the address\t");

    scanf("%s",&s[i].address);
    printf("Your ticket is confirmed\t");
    getch();
}
for (i=0;i<=tickets;i++)
{
    printf("%s", s[i].name);
    printf("%s", s[i].phoneNo);
    printf("%s", s[i].address);
    fprintf(outputFile,"%s",s[i].name);
    fprintf(outputFile,"%s",s[i].phoneNo);
    fprintf(outputFile,"%s",s[i].address);
}
```

Here's what I get in the file:
ûdalla03332228458dallaÈfsÇûÿÿÿÿàrancho03312041265dallabancho

Where are those unusual characters coming from?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) required, what is `struct air`?

Comment: Why are you mixing binary file with text file I/O?

Comment: In C array indexing is `0` based. Change `for (i=1;i<=tickets;i++)` to `for (i=0;i<tickets;i++)`

Comment: As you have not written any `newline` to file to demark your string data, you will have fine old muddle reading the data back in.

Comment: Strings are not read like `scanf("%s",&s[i].address);` please drop the `&`. And be aware that addresses usually contain spaces, so `scanf("%s", ...)` will stop at the first space.

Comment: OP says one of the fields is an `int`.  Guess that is `phoneNo`, so `scanf("%s",&s[i].phoneNo);` indicates OP does not have compiler warnings fully enabled.  (Use `"%d"`)

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for pointing out all the problems! very silly mistakes my bad omg. :P im still unsure about what to do with the string input tho as gets ive heard is dangerous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input loop is

```
for (i=1;i<=tickets;i++)
```

but the output loop is

```
for (i=0;i<=tickets;i++)
```

So you are writing data to file from element `[0]` that you have no data entered for. That is why it is junk.

In C, arrays are indexed from `[0]`, and neither of those loops is right. Please change both of them to

```
for (i = 0; i < tickets; i++)
```

There are other problems in the code too, but this addresses the immediate "uninitialised data" problem.

**Edit:** some other problems.

You opened the file in "binary" mode, but you are using it as a text file. I believe the distinction is only necessary in Windows.

```
FILE *outputFile=fopen("1021.txt", "at");   // change to "t"
```

The string address passed to `scanf` should not contain an `&` address-of (unlike an `int`). Just pass the array - it decays to the required pointer.

```
scanf("%s", s[i].name);                     // removed `&`
```

As you have not written any newline to file to demark your string data, when you read the data back in, you will not know where each ends and the next begins. So for example, add the `newline` like this

```
fprintf(outputFile, "%s\n", s[i].name);     // added \n
```

You say one member is an `int` presumably the phone number, but you are inputting as a string. Yet it is a bad idea to store phone numbers as integers, because a) thay might contain a character such as `'+'` or b) may start with a leading `0` and that will be lost when you store as `int`. So change the struct member `phoneNo` to be a `char` array of adequate length.

The `scanf` format specifier `%s` will stop at the first whitespace it meets, so the input statements will be better as this, which will only stop when it finds a `newline` or hits the length limit:

```
int res = scanf("%29[^\n]", s[i].name);
```

where the array length defined was `[30]` (you did not show the struct). Alternatively you could research the use of `fgets()`.

Finally, you should check the return value of the functions you are calling to see if they were successful. `fopen` will tell you if the file opened correctly. `scanf` will tell you the number of entries it scanned, and `fgets` tells you if it was successful too.